# Web Scraping using Selenium from a list of URLs

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a list of urls in a csv file that I want to **scrape** content from. The csv has 200 plus urls. The code that I'm running is picking the first url and then failing. Here is the code:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver

with open('Godzilla1.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(["Title", "Content"])

f = open("links.csv")
urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

for url in urls:
    
    driver.get(url)
    
    titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="entry-title"]')
    contents = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("et_pb_post")
    
    num_page_items = len(titles)
    with open('Godzilla1.csv', 'a') as f:
        for i in range(num_page_items):
            f.write(titles[i].text + "," + contents[i].text + "\n")

# Clean up (close browser once completed task).
driver.close()
```

When that code runs the error reported is: f.write(titles[i].text + "," + contents[i].text + "\n")
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `contents[i]` doesn't contain `num_page_items` elements.

Comment: can you print num_page_items to see what value you get?

Comment: whats the first url?

Comment: or better yet, can you give a small list (like 5) of those urls?

Comment: your problem can not be solved using information from the post
also, I suggest you to use `driver.quit()` instead of  `driver.close()`, and to put that inside the `for` loop

Answer (score -1):

The problem is while you get 2 items in `titles`, there's only 1 element in `contents`. So as you iterate to the 2nd item in `title`, the `content` is out of range (hence the error). It appears the title content repeats twice, so rather than get all elements with entry-title class, just get the first element.

You're also going to run into issues here using the `,` as you delimiter, as there are commas in the content. Can I suggest just using pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver


f = open("links.csv")
urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

driver = webdriver.Firefox()


rows = []
for url in urls:
    
    driver.get(url)
    
    title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2[@class="entry-title"]')
    content = driver.find_element_by_class_name("et_pb_post")
    
    row = {'Title':title.text,
           'Content':content.text}

  
    
    rows.append(row)
    
# Clean up (close browser once completed task).
driver.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.to_csv('Godzilla1.csv', index=False)
```

There is also the option to avoid Selenium and simply use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


f = open("links.csv")
urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

rows = []
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    title = soup.find('h2',{'class':"entry-title"})
    content = soup.find('div',{'class':'entry-content'}).find('p')
    
    post_meta = soup.find('p', {'class':'post-meta'})

    try:
        category = post_meta.find('a',{'rel':'category tag'}).text.strip()
    except:
        category = ''

    row = {'Title':title.text,
       'Content':content.text,
       'Category':category}
    
    print(row)
    rows.append(row)
    

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.to_csv('Godzilla1.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: These are the first 3 urls in the file @chitown88

```
https://iahomeworkfree.com/in-2006-gitta-contributed-property-with-a-basis-of-500000-and-a-fair-market-value/
https://iahomeworkfree.com/gazelle-manufacturing-is-a-major-producer-of-farm-equipment-2/
https://iahomeworkfree.com/a-top-five-draft-pick-of-fc-football-and-his-agent-are-evaluating-three-contract-options-2
```

Comment: can you give an example where more than 1 title is showing? These examples only have 1 title, but you are iterating through multiple tiltes.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Iterating through multiple titles is a logic error on my code, coz really what I want to do is iterate through the urls that I have in the csv, and scrap the content i.e. the title and content of the website. All the urls are of websites that have the same structure as those 3 urls.

Comment: The selenium code you have provided @chitown88 worked like a charm. The other one is throwing errors. Much appreciation from me.

Comment: @GennieM, I added 1 thing to that second code. Can you try it again and see if that fixed it. also be sure to accept the solution if it met your needs.

Comment: I have tried running the updated second code. Not throwing errors, but i can't see where it is downloading the file with the scrapped data to.

Comment: Should be same folder that the py file is in. You could also explicitly put the path in there. Ie. 'C:/Output/file.csv'

Comment: The python script is running, but it is either failing midway as there is no output file where the py file is.

Comment: well since theres no errors, then you'll need to debug on your end, as it works on my side. You can debug by adding print statements and seeing what the code is producing to narrow down the exact problem. Also, I did see a typo. So I fixed that as well

Comment: Hey @chitown, It's doing. I'd also want to know how can I get to extact the post meta content. Specifically, category, keeping in mind some entries will not have a category and will thus need an error catching phrase?

Comment: I’ll add that in tomorrow morning

Comment: Is it possible to introduce asychronous scrapping with this code?

Comment: I've never needed to do that, so I'm unfamiliar with implementing that. But I don't see why you couldn't do that.